# Jasmine/Karma - the first test case always get failed

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

i have multiple test cases in .spec.ts file. The first test case always get failed with error message 
Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.

Could somebody help me please?

Code snippet:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {  

      jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 2147483647;
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          imports: [AppModule, JobModule],
          providers: [ {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/'} ]
      }).compileComponents();

      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(JobListComponent);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
      debugElement = fixture.debugElement;

      translateService = TestBed.get(TranslateService);
      jobService = TestBed.get(JobService);
      route = TestBed.get(ActivatedRoute);
      _locale = TestBed.get(LOCALE_ID);     


  }));

it('should create the job list component', async(() => { //always this gets failed 
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();             
}));

it('should create the job list component 1', async(() => {              
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();             
}));
```

Comment: Remove the async() call in the beforeEach()

Comment: Thanks rrd. It is working when I run that particulat spec.ts file alone. But when I try to run all the spec.ts files in the project I get errors

****Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'afe' of undefined*****

*****Unhandled Promise rejection: 'expect' was used when there was no current spec, this could be because an asynchronous test timed out ; Zone: ProxyZone ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: 'expect' was used when there was no current spec, this could be because an asynchronous test timed out*****

Comment: You can probably remove the async() on the it() blocks too.

Comment: Thanks...It is working fine for the it() blocks which don't have  subscribe calls. 
In my code, I have another it() block which has subscribe call and has to wait for the result. I use the code *********it('should initialize data on ngOnInit()', (done) => {                        
        component.ngOnInit();       
        fixture.detectChanges();        
        fixture.whenStable().then(()=>{                                  
            expect(component.jobDatabase.data.length).toBeGreaterThanOrEqual(0);   
            done();         
        });        
    });**************

Answer (score 1):

The below code worked for me. Thanks rrd for your great help...

```
it('should create the data list component', () => {                  
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();             
    });

    it('should initialize data on ngOnInit()', (done) => {                               
        component.ngOnInit();              
        fixture.detectChanges();    

        fixture.whenStable().then(()=>{                                                              
            expect(component.customerList.length).toBeGreaterThanOrEqual(0);   
            done(); 
        });  

    });
```